# Admob Rewarded video - Root view controller issue

Tags: ios, swift, admob

So I have two view controllers in my application:

`StartViewController (Root view controller)` and `GameViewController`

I am presenting my Rewarded video from `GameViewController`

Everything works perfectly, except for when the user presses "Skip now" on the rewarded video. It dismisses `GameViewController` and goes back to `StartViewController` which is my root view controller.

If the user watches the entire video, it works as intended.

The code for presenting rewarded view from `GameViewController`:

```
func playReward()
{
    if rewardVideo!.isReady
    {
        if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController
            {
                // Make top controller topmost view controller
                topController = presentedViewController
            }

            rewardVideo!.present(fromRootViewController: topController)
        }
    }
}
```

I temporarily changed the root to `GameViewController` to see if this was the issue and doing so fixed it, so I know it is an issue related to the root view controller and the "Skip now" button on the rewarded video.

Comment: What do you get when you print the eventual top view controller?

Comment: @Callam GameViewController

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by overriding the `func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil` method.

Here is what I did.

```
var didOpenRewardedVideo:Int = 0 
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    if didOpenRewardedVideo == 1 {
        didOpenRewardedVideo = 2
        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
    else if didOpenRewardedVideo == 2{
        didOpenRewardedVideo = 0
    }
    else{
        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
func showRewardedVideo()
{
    didOpenRewardedVideo = 1
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
}
```

Before showing the rewardedAd, do not forget to check if it's ready or not.

```
GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == true
```

When rewardedAd is presented `didOpenRewardedVideo` is set to 1. When user dismissing rewardedAd `didOpenRewardedVideo` is 1 and calling `super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)`. Then `didOpenRewardedVideo` is set to 2. Now I know `dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` will be called once more. This time I don't call the `super` method and set `didOpenRewardedVideo` to 0. I know if I dismiss my `UIViewController` will be dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

@mialkan,

your solution does not work. I don't why no one talk about this issue. I am also facing such problem.

Answer (score 0):

import GoogleMobileAds **import sdk in your class or viewcontroller**

GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate **Add this in your class or viewcontroller**

var  RewardBasedVideo: GADRewardBasedVideoAd? **initialize AdController object **

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    RewardBasedVideo=GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()
    RewardBasedVideo?.delegate = self
}
```

//MARK:- WATCH AD BUTTON CLICK

```
 @IBAction func WatchAdBtn_Click(_ sender: UIButton)
 {
    if RewardBasedVideo?.isReady == true
     {
        RewardBasedVideo?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else
     {
     //Show alert here "Ads is not ready to load"
    }
}

func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) 
{
    print("Reward based video ad is closed.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who is facing the the same issue:

You can create a new class for your `rootViewController` (`TabBarController` or `NavigationController` etc.) and implement there something like that:

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    dismissalCounter += 1
    if (dismissalCounter < 2) {
       super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    dismissalCounter = 0
}

override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    dismissalCounter = 0
    super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
}

var dismissalCounter : Int = 0
```

Important! Use this functions inside `TabBarController` or `NavigationController`, otherwise it is not gonna work

**UPD:**
In my case unfortunatly it breaks all NavigationControllers inside a `TabBarController` (titles don't show and there are no buttons inside them), if I will figure fix actions, I'll let you know

**UPD2:**
Pretty obvious decision will be to change the `initialViewController` and view add from it, it'll not be dismissed

**UPD3:**
I solved this very and very strange:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {  
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady == false {
             let request = GADRequest()
            rewardBasedVideo!.load(request, withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
        }
    }

    var rewardBasedVideo: GADRewardBasedVideoAd?

    @IBAction func ad_button_click(_ sender: Any) {
        if rewardBasedVideo!.isReady == true     {
            let bl = blur()
            self.present(bl, animated: true, completion: {
                self.rewardBasedVideo?.present(fromRootViewController: bl)
            })

        }
    }

}

class blur : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        checkForKeyWindow()
    }

    func checkForKeyWindow() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
            if (UIApplication.topViewController() == self) {
                print("dismissed and forgotten")
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                print("not keywindow")
                self.checkForKeyWindow()
            }
        })
    }

    @objc func close() {
       self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }

        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            let moreNavigationController = tab.moreNavigationController

            if let top = moreNavigationController.topViewController, top.view.window != nil {
                return topViewController(base: top)
            } else if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }

        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }

        return base
    }
}
```